# Can't scroll to bottom in UISearchResultsTableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm facing a really strange problem, where I can not scroll to the bottom in `UISearchResultsTableView`altough the frame of the tableView and the contentSize is correct.

It only happens if I click on "Cancel" and enter a new search string. If I clear this string and enter again, everything works fine. If I click "Cancel" again and enter a new string, I can't scroll to the bottom. It seems to me like the second search works, but I'm having a problem with the first search or after clicking the "Cancel" button in `UISearchBar`.

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self searchForText:searchString];
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.rowHeight = 70;
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide
{

    UITableView *tableView = [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView];

    [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

    [tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

I've also subclassed my `UISearchDisplayController`

```
- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.active == visible) return;

    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [super setActive:visible animated:animated];
    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    if (visible) {
       [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
       [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Additionally I'm also using a custom cell, which is registered like this

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView
 registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"..." bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"..."];
```

Comment: Can you scroll your tableview before you searching?

Comment: Yes, and also after clicking the clear button (little x) and typing in the search again. But if I press cancel and type in again, I can't scroll to bottom, but contentSize is correct and also frame of tableView.

Comment: try to play with contentInsets for tableView. Maybe disable auto layout

Comment: The contentOffset is (0,0) which I guess is correct?

Comment: contentInsets this one

Comment: How have you implemented your table delegate methods? Is it that you expect to see more rows, or you can see them but the scroll content is too small?

Comment: @Wain I think it's the issue with tableView content, when  you can't see last cell or something like that

Comment: @Wain I would expect to see 3 more rows. I can see them with the scroll and hold trick.

Comment: @Anton Unfortunately setting `tableView.contentInset` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`does not help either.

Comment: did you try to disable auto layout?

Comment: @Anton I'm using auto layout in many other viewControllers, therefore I can not disable it.

Comment: ContentInsets will work after disable auto layout. Just try.

Comment: @Anton still the same if a disable auto layout. The weird thing is it works if I clear the searchBar and enter the search string again.

Answer (score 5):

I solve the problem, I think you need to check you tableview contentInset property in tableview "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method. It's not UIEdgeInsetsZero. I solved it by set tableview content Inset to UIEdgeInsetsZero in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method. It's a little wired, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - apparently an Apple bug - on simulator the inset doesn't change...Filed a radar 18629948

Comment: How/why does this enable scrolling of the `UITableView`?